# add new data with ExcelWriter() without deleting old data in excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to add data to excel sheet from pandas library. Now I am needed to add new data without deleting old data in excel sheet
My Code:

```py
editableExcelSheet = pd.ExcelWriter(r'D:\Projects\MOJ\MOJ.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

serialNumberFromSheet_htmlName = request.form.get("serialNumberFromSheet_htmlName")
dataSet = {'Serial Number': [serialNumberFromSheet_htmlName]}        
newCase = pd.DataFrame(dataSet)
newCase.to_excel(editableExcelSheet, sheet_name='Sheet1')
editableExcelSheet.save()
```

Comment: In the [home page](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/introduction.html) of `xlsxwriter`, they say : __it cannot read or modify existing Excel XLSX files__. That means if you want to append data to an existing spreadsheet, you need to use `openpyxl`.